# Google Chrome Extension for Transparent Tabs or Windows

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-tab

Is it possible to create a browser extension that would allow page-controlled window opacity? Not so that various elements on the page are of a given opacity, but to allow one to see other windows (like the desktop) behind the browser page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible in an extension.  Such transparency would be handled at the window manager level, and would require platform-specific code.  This means that either Chrome would have to add this feature and expose it as an extension API ([currently no such feature exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191160/163956)), or you would have to write a plugin.